# How to find the app crash when installed by Test flight in Objective c?

Tags: ios, testflight, crash-reports

I did set release mode in my app. but after that, also the crash has occur, when install by test flight. please answer me to solve this.

Comment: You can try by integrating Crashlytics.

Comment: @SherM4n Why?  Apple provide a perfectly good crash report, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

The most useful and used third party are :-
[fabric](https://get.fabric.io) and [instabug](https://instabug.com)